# xcode, nslog weird hitch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

The code below gives me an NSLog redirect location on a tinyurl link when clicking on a tinyurl link. However, if I remove the following piece of code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];`, it will give me the actual website in NSLog and not the tinyurl link. How can I make it where I can have the actual website URL in NSLog while the share application code is presented?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  {
    NSLog(@"Redirect Location: %@",[request.URL absoluteString]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
}
```

Comment: You're saying if you remove the second line of this method, you get a different result from the first line? Can you provide some code we can run that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Yes, the code should be posted above. Just try to link a web view to a site with bitly URL.

Comment: To test that, one would have to create an entire application with a web view. You must have done some testing of your own -- including minimizing the code -- trying to solve this, so share the results of that.

Comment: I believe the problem is UIAPPLICATION opens up before request url fully reads it. Is there a solution to stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Using `UIWebViewDelegate` method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is not a great mechanism for figuring out to which site you'll be redirected (especially since, judging from your code, you'll ultimately opening it in an external app, not your `UIWebView`), because you're getting `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` before the redirect takes place. You can, though, use `NSURLConnection` and [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011348-CH1-SW9) methods to figure out where you'll eventually be redirected.

Long answer:

If you look at `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, if you return `YES`, you'll let the `UIWebView` follow the redirect requests. Consider the following `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"%@", request.URL);
    return YES;
}
```

If you use this with the a random `bit.ly` URL, say, `http://nyti.ms/Yi6EAk`, you'll see the following log:

```
2013-03-12 21:23:31.418 webtest[6959:c07] http://nyti.ms/Yi6EAk
2013-03-12 21:23:31.511 webtest[6959:c07] http://bit.ly/Yi6EAk?cc=0d7134b272b1004cb954d0400076e9fa
2013-03-12 21:23:31.560 webtest[6959:c07] http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/13/us/politics/ryans-plan-aims-to-balance-budget-in-10-years.html?hp&_r=0
```

That third call to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is the actual URL for which I defined the `bit.ly` redirect URL, i.e. the final destination of two consecutive redirects. But if your `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` returned `NO`, then you'll never figure out to which site it would ultimately be redirected. (And by the way, your `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` should definitely return `YES` or `NO` ... your sample doesn't return either.)

As you can see, because `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` happens before the redirect has a chance to take place, you'll see each and every redirect taking place. Depending upon what the resulting site does, you may see subsequent `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` calls as the page retrieves extra content. This makes this an awkward mechanism for finding out what site to which you were ultimately redirected.

If you really need the site you're being redirected to, you might want to use `NSURLConnection`, instead. While that is generally used for actually retrieving the data from the server, it can also be used for capturing the redirects (but not suffering from the problems of the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, where it's tough to differentiate between genuine redirects from just random additional content that the page may subsequently request).

So consider the following:

```
self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nyti.ms/Yi6EAk"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

You can then implement `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`, a `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method, that will track the various redirects:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.url = request.URL;

    return request;
}
```

Clearly, because you're using `NSURLConnection` to track the redirects, but we don't really care about the `responseData` that we generally use `NSURLConnection` to retrieve, we can just cancel the connection as soon as you receive a good response (confident that we already know to which site were finally redirected):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [connection cancel];

    NSLog(@"Ok, we now know that the resulting URL is %@", self.url);
}
```

You might, by the way, also want to capture connection errors, for example:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Ok, we failed trying to retrieve data from %@", self.url);
}
```

In closing, it's worth pointing out that this technique, of making the HTTP request with `NSURLConnection` and letting it follow the whole series of redirects, is a pretty inefficient process, so you'll have to decide whether it's worth it. But this is one way to figure out where your HTTP redirects will lead you.

One final caveat, this captures traditional redirects, but if the page is doing any client-side JavaScript redirects, I don't think this technique will work. It works for the vast majority of redirected HTTP requests, though.

Comment: Ooo ... nice answer, you saved me! +1