# Is there any way to turn a bit.ly to a full url using Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink, bit.ly

I am wondering if this is actually possible,because I am running out of solutions for my problem.The bit.ly short links are just ruining my day lol. The code below is what I am trying to pull off, but this doesn't work with bit.ly links. And it is always detecting bit.ly  links first then google redirected links next.

```
 -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
 if ([[inRequest.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google"].location==NSNotFound){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable for you to [edit your previous unanswered post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371404/xcode-nslog-weird-hitch) about the same problem than repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to expand the bit.ly link you'll need to make another web service call.  [LongUrl](http://longurl.org) offers a service to expand shortened URLs.  They offer a [API](http://longurl.org/api) to provide this.

You'll just have to live with the extra latency of a second request.

Comment: I am not certain how to implement this. Do I need to download anything for this and how will I insert the code?

Comment: Read the API, it looks pretty straightforward to me.  The shortened URL is going to need to be decoded and a service like this will help you.  They seemed like a good fit because they decode other shorteners as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Bitly API's [expand](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand) endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick, easy and thread-safe way of getting any short URL to the original URL

**Link:** https://github.com/emotality/ATURLExpander

**Example:**

```
[[ATURLExpander urlEngine] expandURL:@"http://bit.ly/1dNVPAW" withBlock:^(NSError *error, NSString *longURL) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ATURLExpander ERROR : '%@'", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ATURLExpander URL : '%@'", longUrl);
    }
}];
```